# Make a trigger to get the difference between the dates

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

```
CREATE TRIGGER ci_insert
AFTER INSERT ON tb 
REFERENCING NEW AS nr
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  date_from DATE;
  date_to   DATE;
  diff  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT DATE_FROM INTO date_from WHERE id = :nr.id;
  SELECT DATE_TO INTO date_to WHERE id = :nr.id;
  diff = date_to - date_from;
  UPDATE TB SET (diff) VALUES (diff) WHERE id = :nr.id;
END;
```

I use sqlplus and it just doesn't work. It even doesn't show any errors. What can it be?

Comment: What is RDMS? If it's Oracle, you must have `FROM ` in `SELECT DATE_FROM `, `SELECT DATE_TO`

Comment: This looks like good definition, total offhand guess would be it's getting confused on ambiguous name 'diff'.  It appears that both your column name in the table as well as local var are named the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few mistakes. First of all, you must have `FROM` in every select. Secondly, you will have runtime error about mutating table - you cannot read/write to the same table which triggers action in row-level trigger. Finally, your `UPDATE` has wrong syntax, it looks more like `INSERT`; update syntax is `UPDATE table1 SET field1 = value1 WHERE ....`

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER ci_insert
AFTER INSERT ON tb 
REFERENCING NEW AS nr
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  date_from DATE;
  date_to   DATE;
  diff  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT DATE_FROM INTO date_from from TB WHERE id = :nr.id;
  SELECT DATE_TO INTO date_to from TB WHERE id = :nr.id;
  diff = date_to - date_from;
  UPDATE TB SET (diff) VALUES (diff) WHERE id = :nr.id;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is this - I always try my queries on existing tables if possible. Replace table name with your_table...:

```
   Begin
     Update emp_test
        Set empno = (Select trunc(sysdate)-to_date('20-DEC-2012') days_btwn From dual);
   End;
```